Extension of $ZFC$ model that preserves subset of z but Comprehension fails at z
Does anyone have a good counterexample (or proof, though I would be surprised if it held) for countable transitive models $M \subseteq N$ such that $M \models ZFC$, $N \models ZFC-Repl.-Comp.$ and $N$ doesn't add subsets of $z$ for some $z \in M$ (i.e. $\forall x: N \models (x \subseteq z) \Rightarrow x \in M)$ but there exists some formula $\phi$ with parameters $y_1, ..., y_n \in M$ such that Comprehension fails in $N$ for $\phi$ and $z$, i.e. $ \{ x \in z : \phi^N(x, y_1, ...,y_n) \} \notin N $?

@FarmerS You're of course right. Yes I want the model N to at least fulfill ZFC-Comprehension-Replacement, I edited the question now. Thanks for the comment!

@FarmerS Though on a further note, could you clarify what the z and $\phi$ actually are in your example? Since I require a to lie in M and $\phi$ to only use parameters in M, the obvious case of z=y and $\phi(a)= a \textit{ is finite} $ needn't work

Hmm, okay, sorry, I missed that you wanted the parameters in $M$. So that example is not relevant.

Assume there is a transitive model of ZFC, and let $L_\alpha$ be the minimal one. So $\alpha$ is countable. Fix a sequence $\left<\kappa_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ of $L_\alpha$-regular cardinals, with
$\omega<\kappa_0$, $(\kappa_n^{+\omega})^{L_\alpha}<\kappa_{n+1}$, and $\sup_{n<\omega}\kappa_n=\alpha$.
Let $\left<G_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ be such that $G_n$ is $L_\alpha[G_0,\ldots,G_{n-1}]$-generic for adding a surjection $\kappa_n\to\kappa_n^{+L_\alpha}$, with conditions being functions $f:\beta\to\kappa_n^{+L_\alpha}$ for some $\beta<\kappa_n$ (with $f\in L_\alpha[G_0,\ldots,G_{n-1}]$),
ordered by extension.
Now by choosing the $\kappa_n$'s a little more carefully, we can code an arbitrary real into them, in particular some real $x\notin L_\alpha$.
For example, let $\kappa_n=\lambda^{+L_\alpha}$ for some $L_\alpha$-limit cardinal $\lambda$, if $n\notin x$, and let $\kappa_n=\lambda^{++L_\alpha}$ for some such $\lambda$, if $n\in x$. (Of course $\lambda$ varies with $n$.)
Now let $M=L_\alpha$ and $N=\bigcup_{n<\omega}L_\alpha[G_0,\ldots,G_{n-1}]$.
Then $(M,N)$ are such a pair; we have $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^M=\mathcal{P}(\omega)^N$, but $x$ is definable over $N$ without parameters, by recovering the $\kappa_n$'s definably over $N$ (without parameters), and hence $x$. This can be done as for all $m<\omega$ with $m> n$, $L_\alpha[G_0,\ldots,G_{n}]$ and $L_\alpha[G_0,\ldots,G_{m-1}]$ and $N$ all have the same $\mathcal{P}(\kappa_n^{+\omega})$, and hence the fact that $\kappa_n^{+L_\alpha}$
is not a cardinal in $N$, but is a cardinal in $L_\alpha$, can be used to identify $\kappa_n$. And, using the preceding considerations, it is also straightforward to check the axioms of ZFC other than Collection and Separation.
